# Workbench issues with spfx 18.2 and react 16.8.4

Tags: spfx-webparts, reactjs, gulp, webpack, workbench

I have recently updated a number of modern spfx webparts to spfx 18.2 and this morning when I try to debug in workbench (locally and on tenant) I am getting serve errors in relation to react and react-dom

I am able to serve projects not using react successfully but when using spfx 18.2 but not react 16.8.4 - has anybody else encountered this issue.

I have restored to previous code backup, as well as restoring to previous days last git commit neither had a positive effect.

I get no errors in terminal but workbench shows the following message:

```
SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]:
***Failed to load component "174429f3-8ff8-4143-8f12-7c398d264e9a" (FusionWebPartWebPart).
Original error: ***Failed to load URL 'https://localhost:4321/node_modules/react/dist/react.js' for resource 'react' in component '174429f3-8ff8-4143-8f12-7c398d264e9a' (FusionWebPartWebPart). The file was not found in the server.
Make sure that you are running 'gulp serve'.

    INNERERROR:
    ***Failed to load URL 'https://localhost:4321/node_modules/react/dist/react.js' for resource 'react' in component '174429f3-8ff8-4143-8f12-7c398d264e9a' (FusionWebPartWebPart). The file was not found in the server.
    Make sure that you are running 'gulp serve'.
    ***CALLSTACK:
    Error
        at SPLoaderError.SPError [as constructor] (https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_default.js:8390:24)
        at new SPLoaderError (https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_default.js:4036:28)
        at Function.ErrorBuilder.buildErrorWithVerboseLog (https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_default.js:3789:21)
        at Function.ErrorBuilder.buildLoadComponentError (https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_default.js:3697:21)
        at https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_default.js:6275:47
```

Comment: When I review the temp folder and the node-modules folder for react the 'dist' folder does not exist - how can this be?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with react 16.8.x. No solution yet. The issue is that loader is looking in the wrong place for react.js - in react 15 the path was react/dist/react.js, but with the release of react 16 it changed to react/umd/react.development.js (https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html). For some reason the SPFx loader is treating it as a react 15 build.

Answer (score 3):

Insert 2 lines to your gulpfile.js

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const gulp = require('gulp');
const build = require('@microsoft/sp-build-web');
build.addSuppression(`Warning - [sass] The local CSS class 'ms-Grid' is not camelCase and will not be type-safe.`);

build.configureWebpack.mergeConfig({
    additionalConfiguration: (generatedConfiguration) => {
        if (!generatedConfiguration.resolve.alias) {
            generatedConfiguration.resolve.alias = {};
        }
        generatedConfiguration.resolve.alias['@utils'] = path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib/utils');
        generatedConfiguration.resolve.alias['@src'] = path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib');

        /////  insert these 2 lines ////////////
        generatedConfiguration.externals.splice(generatedConfiguration.externals.indexOf('react'), 1);
        generatedConfiguration.externals.splice(generatedConfiguration.externals.indexOf('react-dom'), 1);

        return generatedConfiguration;
    }
});

build.initialize(gulp);
```

and after:

```
gulp clean
gulp build
gulp serve
```

Comment: Doesn't work either, for me.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the best thing to start is **gulp clean**
Then **gulp build** and then **gulp serve**.

Maybe these simple steps will help you to refresh all dependencies and get rid of outdated artifacts

Comment: I fixed it by doing the above after delleting my bode modules and rerunning npm install

Comment: Did that, doesn't work for me.